# Undefined parameter used within function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading Redux tutorial and in a code snipped there is 'prevCounter' variable used without being initialized - '()' has no param within it. How is it possible that prevCounter can be used within setCounter call? Is prevCounter by default initialized with counter state thanks to arrow syntax used when calling setCounter and incremented prevCounter is implicitly returned?

Here is the snippet:

```
function Counter() {
  // State: a counter value
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  // Action: code that causes an update to the state when something happens
  const increment = () => {
    setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1)
  }

  // View: the UI definition
  return (
    <div>
      Value: {counter} <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

URL to the tutorial: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: When using the arrow function we can omit the { brackets } and ( parentheses ) and "return".
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code `prevCounter => prevCounter + 1` is an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). That means that when the function `increment` (has no paramter) is called, it will trigger the `setCounter` function with a callback function (the arrow function above). This callback function takes the parameter `prevCounter`, adds one to it and returns the value. Internally the `setCounter` function stores somehow the current value and the value will be passed as the parameter `prevCounter` to the callback function every time `setCounter` is called.

Comment: So prevCounter is internally initialized with counter state value by the setCounter function?

Comment: Yes, it is initialized with counter state value by the setCounter function

Answer (score 0):

Just use `counter` variable, like

```
function Counter() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  const increment = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Value: {counter} <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  )
}

Please try it and let me know. Hope it should do.
```

Comment: So my question is: Is this line 'setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1)' correct in this case? This is a snippet from a tutorial - not my own so i thought it is correct.